# attributing more than one list or elements in c#

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a problem
When I do

```
[XmlAttribute("Item")]
public List<PlaylistItem> Items { get; set; }
```

`"<PlaylistItem> Items"` changes `"Exm"` but i want to change just `"<PlaylistItem>"` to `"Exm"`

How can I change just `PlaylistItem` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, I know this works for arrays. Not sure about Lists.

```
[XmlArrayItem("Item")]
public List<PlaylistItem> Items { get; set; }
```